# What's the best way to delete an item from a nested NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a nested series of NSMutableDictionaries that contain an NSMutableArray.  I'd like a quick way to delete one item from the array.

For example:

NSMutableDictionary dict contains:

```
{
    "foo" =     {
        "bar" =         {
            "baz" =             (
                "<MyItem: 0x17409d100>"
            );
        };
    };
}
```

I thought I would be able to remove it by:

```
// MyItem *myItemToDelete = pointer to <MyItem: 0x17409d100>

NSMutableArray *tmp = [[[dict objectForKey:@"foo"] objectForKey:@"bar"] objectForKey:@"baz"];
[tmp removeObject:myItemToDelete];
currentImage = nil;
```

However, executing the above, tmp is nil, currentImage is nil, but the original dict still has the reference to the MyItem object.

Comment: Check for the value returned by the key on every level independently. Probably a typo. BTW: If it works, `[dict valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bar.baz"]` will work, too.

Comment: Dang it -- that's exactly it.  "baz" (in my actual app) was returning nil because it hadn't been set properly.

Comment: This is where swift is awesome. This literally can't happen.

Comment: @Fogmeister - That's a strange (and out of place) statement. Looking up an invalid key in Objective-C returns `nil`, in Swift an optional indicating the key wasn't present. In both languages you then test the return value. For multiple key lookup where one fails Objective-C would propagate the `nil` and Swift would propagate the optional. There are some fundamental differences in approach between the two languages, but surely indicating failure on key lookup is not one of them? Or maybe I just misunderstood your comment completely, if so I'll put it down to partying ;-)

Comment: @Fogmeister Yeah, if you believe in commercials …

Comment: @CRD what I meant was that in swift you cannot just carry on as though the object exists. This problem occurred because the value hadn't been checked and was assumed to be ok. In swift it won't allow this because the optional would force you (at compile time) to check and unwrap it. :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister - but you can surely, it's called [*optional chaining*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) which Apple themselves compare to invoking messages on `nil`. But as I said, we're off topic for this question, let's leave it.